Unable to post LaTeX without code tags
I recently made a post on Mathematica stackexchange, that made extensive use of LaTeX: Find perspective projection matrix under constraints
However, upon trying to post the original post, it would error with "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code", asking me to enclose it with code tags. I had 173 reputation at the time
So I edited my post to add the code tags around the LaTeX and it successfully posted, but MathJax no longer picks it up and formats it. (Afterwards, a user with high reputation edited the code tags out since they seem to be able to ignore the error)
This seems to be a common issue on stackexchange, and I quickly found related reports:

https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8514/error-about-improperly-formatted-code-appears-when-attempting-to-format-latex-as
Cannot post my question because of code formatting
Cannot post question using specific MathJax because of warning about missing code formatting
Post contains a code that is not properly formatted

So this is just another instance of the known bug that goes back years, that seems to stem from: First-time posts with unformatted code should be automatically caught
